# PostgreSQL 9.3: SELECT within REPLACE()

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables as shown below:

Table1 : Test1

```
Create table Test1
(
  name varchar(50) 
);
```

Insertion: I have 5 millions records in this table.

```
insert into Test1 values('a$xyz');  
insert into Test1 values('xyz$a');
```

Table2 : Test2

```
create table Test2
(
  pattern varchar(50)
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into Test2 values('a$');
insert into Test2 values('$a');
```

Now I want to update the table Test1. Specifically I want to update the name in the table by replacing the pattern of table Test2.

Like:

```
update Test1
set name = replace(name,'a$','');
```

How can I get the string_to_replace from the table Test2? As per my knowledge we can't use SELECT within REPLACE function.

Comment: Did you mean to write `update test1`? And how would you find the pattern to be used for the replacement? How are those two tables linked?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry! That was typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a problem:

```
UPDATE test1
SET name = replace(name, pattern, '')
FROM test2
WHERE pattern = 'a$';
```

But this is all a bit superfluous. Assuming you had some 'id' in table 'test2' then it would become more useful:

```
UPDATE test1
SET name = replace(name, pattern, '')
FROM test2
WHERE id = 17;
```